# Assigning categories to markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with several markers, I can't do an array as this page needs to be independent (no external sources). I need to assign each marker with an index so I can create a checkbox, pulldown or slider control to turn off/on the category of markers needed. So lets say I have 10 markers, 2 in each category (1-5) I need to be able to say category 1 and 3 and shut off the others. How can I do this easily? Can someone recommend code that I can insert into my functions to zoomTo those specified groups?

```
// Start of Marker8 (red - marker color)
var latLng8 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.18, 101.40);
var contentString8 = '<div id="content">'+
   '<p><b>Driving Directions</b><br>Enter your start address <form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">' +
    '<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=40 name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br><br>' +
                '<input value="Get Directions to this place" type="submit">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="XX.XX, -XX.XX"></p>'+    
                '</div>';
                var infowindow8 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString8
                });
                var marker8 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng8,
                    icon: src = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png',
                    map: map,
                    title: "place 1"
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker8, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow8.open(map, marker8);
                });
                // End for Marker 7
```

Comment: I would love to produce an example, but I do not want to recreate the whole setup from scrath.

Comment: I want to do exactly this http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html but I need to list all of my markers separately in the code, ie. marker 1, 2, 3, etc. Can someone help me incorporate this?

Comment: marker code is here:
        var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.2, -96.2);
        var contentString2 = '<div id="content">';
        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString2
        });
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng2,
            icon: src = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png',
            map: map,
            title: "marker 2"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
            infowindow2.open(map, marker2);

Comment: @davidkonrad if you can recreate the example above geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html but with the ability for me to add markers 1, 2, 3 based on my code above I will PAY you for your time, please help?

Comment: No paying. It is just that i not completely understand _why_, and not want to make all the code from scrath :) Why do you not want an array? It seems weird. But I try to produce a simple example.

Comment: Michael, this has been a loooong process. I agree, but the point is - I finally concluded - not to produce the perfect example but more an educational piece of code. Normally I would not do that, too timeconsuming, but I had the time, there was Champions League in the background :)

Comment: @MichaelGeary I had to remove confidential info out of my code to post on here, not sure why your nitpicking my comments? I am also learning when you write this criticism it kinda frustrates me, I understand this should be an array I DONT KNOW How to do that just yet. If I am asking the wrong questions I am sorry, post how this SHOULD be done and I can learn from that? David was just getting me to a solution quickly to my issue. Another thing is I am creating a template to automate with FME, I get need to get this to work so I can move on. I am not a developer!

Comment: I have little time to work on this as is, I need to be able to add my own marker info to this (array)? Instead of the random marker generator. If there is a way, can someone tell me and/or add comments so I can learn from this experience? Thank you BOTH! Everytime I try something I break something...

Comment: Bob, I'm sorry for my impatient attitude yesterday. I deleted my previous comments and would like to start over. Even if you only do a little bit of JavaScript, you will find it very helpful to learn about functions, objects, and arrays. David's answer has examples of all three. In particular, an array is always better than individual named variables like `marker1` through `marker8`. David's code actually creates an array called `markerArray`, where `markerArray[0]` is the first marker, `markerArray[1]` the second, etc. (Arrays start with 0, not 1.) See my comment on his answer for more notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example in pure javascript, no external resources, besides the google-code.

It creates a map on a random location. Then it creates 8 markers, also with a random location and category 1-4.

Then there is a select-box showing categories. When you select a category, markers associated with that category is shown, the rest is hidden.

So now it is up to you to set the right center for the map, set the right latLng for the markers, the categories and so on. Hope you see the principle.

script :

```
var marker1, marker2, marker3, marker4, marker5, marker6, marker7, marker8;
var map;
var markersArray = [];

function getRandomLatLng() {
    var lat = Math.random()*30;
    var lng = Math.random()*30;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);  
}

function createMap() {
    var mapCenter = getRandomLatLng();
    console.log(mapCenter);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    });
}

function createMarker(latLng, category) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        category : category
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
    return marker;
}

function createMarkers() {
    marker1=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 1);
    marker2=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 1);
    marker3=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 2);
    marker4=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 2);
    marker5=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 3);
    marker6=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 3);
    marker7=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 4);
    marker8=createMarker(getRandomLatLng(), 4);
}

function showMarkersByCategory(category) {
    for (var i=0;i<markersArray.length;i++) {
        if (markersArray[i].category==category) {
            markersArray[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            markersArray[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

function initialize() {
    createMap();
    createMarkers();
    var select=document.getElementById('select');
    select.onclick = function() {
        var category = this.value;
        showMarkersByCategory(category);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

markup

```
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
<select id="select">
<option value="1">category 1</option>
<option value="2">category 2</option>
<option value="3">category 3</option>
<option value="4">category 4</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: ah no I need the ability to toggle the different groups on/off??

Comment: How can I replace getRandomLatLng with my own marker locations??

Comment: See update. You should really consider learning the basics yourself by reading the documentation, starting from - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple. And you should consider upvote for my effort :) I see a lot "I cannot figure out my copy paste I have from site XXX" - typically, the examples and code around the net are not very good quality, and often more confusing than educational.

Comment: I completely understand and agree with you, I am doing my best to learn the right way to do things. I appreciate all your help and will do what I can. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you use eight separate named variables instead of an array? Wait: you have eight separate named variables *and* an array with the same marker objects? This does not make sense. Yes, I know it's something like what the OP asked for, but no, it still doesn't make sense. You could just have the array and get rid of the named variables. Any reason not to do that?

Comment: Michael, see the comments above the question. Thats how Bob C wanted it. As i comment, i dont quite understand why, but thats OK.

Comment: @davidkonrad - totally understand that, and no criticism of your work intended. Sorry it came across that way! I tend to be kind of stubborn: When someone asks for a solution that is clearly not a good programming practice, I stop them right there instead of giving them what they want. :-)

Comment: Actually your code looks spot on, if you just make two changes: Remove the `var marker1, marker2, ... marker8;` line, and remove the `marker1=`, `marker2=`, etc. assignments so you just call `createMarker`. Then you have all the markers in an array like they should be, without the redundant variables. :-) @BobC: Something for you to understand here is that an array is *just as good for every purpose* as a list of individual numbered variable names. There's nothing at all you could do with the individual variables that you couldn't do just as easily with the array.

Comment: Yes it does, and yes I have static lat/lngs. I would like to learn more, but for now I need to get an assignment done for work. If either of you guy have a better way to do this I invite you to post or email and I would be happy to learn the correct way to accomplish this task(s). Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way I can still get help on this topic, there is discussion regarding how I am doing things. I was hoping I can continue to learn as well as solve my issue. So with the code you provided @davidkonrad or Michael Geary how can I add my own marker content to this? Please help...thanks

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes sir I am how shall we proceed?

Comment: Yes .... What do you need exactly? I am suprised that my editing from yeasterday is gone, by the way- think I made an update by how you added your own lat, lngs, but maybe an error 40 :)

Comment: Let me understand : You want to see how you can assign your own lat/lng's to the markers in the example, and also how you can open a infowindow on click, with some content hold by the markers? I would actually prefer to make the code and send it to you directly. So if the above is what you want, I will make a new example and send it to you (if you give your email, I will save it so you can delete immediately)

Comment: is it okay if the locations array (or object) holds the content? eg [lat, lng, category, content] - you are hardcoding anyway?